# Struggling with Youtube Player Support Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Im trying to use the Youtube Player Support Fragment in a fragment but the app always crash (NullPointerException) and I have not been able to find any similar post to fix it.

I have import import android.support.v4.app.Fragment so that should not be the problem.

This is how my fragment class looks like:

```
package com.example.activitydetector;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import systemManager.SystemManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GuidelinesFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    SystemManager sm;
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView; 
    String URL_VIDEO = "CaA-k1l0xa4";
    String KEY_DEVELOPER = "AIzaSyBIIs0u0NXhsZguv8nCNvSzUmflTt7K1Ek";

    public GuidelinesFragment() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube, container, false);


        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);

        youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(KEY_DEVELOPER, new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,
                    boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg1.cueVideo(URL_VIDEO);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                    YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

This is my totally and simple "Youtube" layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And this is the error that the log shows:

```
    11-30 16:33:56.419: W/dalvikvm(19375): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f14258)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onStart(Unknown Source)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1484)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4645)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-30 16:33:56.423: E/AndroidRuntime(19375):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ANY help or hint would be deeply grateful. I have already wasted around 4 hours without luck.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ran into this problem before and I believe the issue stemmed from trying to inflate the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` layout.  I solved my issue by creating a fragment like this:

```
public class PlayerYouTubeFrag extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {
    private String currentVideoID = "video_id";
    private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;

    public static PlayerYouTubeFrag newInstance(String url) {
        PlayerYouTubeFrag playerYouTubeFrag = new PlayerYouTubeFrag();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);

        playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        return playerYouTubeFrag;
    }

    private void init() {
        initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { 
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                activePlayer = player;
                activePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    activePlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("url"), 0);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onYouTubeVideoPaused() {
        activePlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

And then call an instance of the fragment like this:

```
PlayerYouTubeFrag myFragment = PlayerYouTubeFrag.newInstance("video_id");
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.video_container, myFragment).commit();
```

Where `video_container` in my case was an empty frame layout.

Comment: how about if i want to play 2 or more videos at the same time?

Comment: @Cristiana214 Perhaps instantiate a new fragment and pass it a new video_id.  Then call the fragment manager to replace a different container, passing in your newly created fragment.

Comment: @CzarMatt i can't run the code you posted above the calling instance "getSupportFragmentManager()" is in red

Comment: @CzarMatt please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189802/android-youtube-api-play-two-or-more-youtube-players-in-one-main-activity

Comment: I have the same problem.
I've implemented your solution and there are no exceptions, yet I got black screen where the youtube fragment i.e. the video play doesn't start.

Comment: @ViksaaSkool Are you getting sound at least?  Make sure the YouTube application is updated on your device.

Comment: I've solved the issue and edited your answer but it was deleted. In the solution you've provided, init() has to be called in OnCreate /*just onCreate*/ in order to get video play.

Comment: One thing you forgot, which is essential to make it work (at least for me it was) is RIGHT beneath the line: "playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);", you need to add:  "playerYouTubeFrag.init();". This initializes the init() class, which starts the video.

Comment: Also, since I'm sure people will run into the same issue I did, when you pass in a URL for the video, you are NOT passing in the youtube URL (IE: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7PYqhABiSo&feature=youtu.be") You are passing in only the video ID (IE: "z7PYqhABiSo"). Since it is Google's own documentation, it knows how to play it just fine with the id.

Comment: @CzarMatt Why does onYouTubeVideoPaused have @ Override annotation?  There's no such method in YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.

Comment: @CzarMatt Why are you setting player style to `PlayerStyle.DEFAULT`, when that's already being used, since it's the default style?

Answer (score 6):

CzarMatt nailed it. Just to add to his answer though, don't forget you need to call the `init()` method. To do so follow CzarMatt's code and add one line:

```
public static PlayerYouTubeFrag newInstance(String url) {    
    PlayerYouTubeFrag playerYouTubeFrag = new PlayerYouTubeFrag();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("url", url);

    playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

    playerYouTubeFrag.init(); //This line right here

    return playerYouTubeFrag;
}
```

Also, since I'm sure people will run into the same issue I did, even though CzarMatt mentioned it above, just to reiterate, when you pass in a URL for the video, you are NOT passing in the youtube URL

That is, with: `"youtube.com/watch?v=z7PYqhABiSo&feature=youtu.be"`

You are passing in only the video ID

I.e. use: `"z7PYqhABiSo"`

Since it is Google's own documentation, it knows how to play it just fine with the id.