# Android: NoClassDefFoundError with YouTubePlayerFragment on Gingerbread

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm using the Youtube API to play Youtube videos in my Android app.  It works fine on newer phones, but when I try to run on a device running Gingerbread, I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment; (21)
Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment;' failed
VFY: unable to resolve static method 9606: Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment;.newInstance ()Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment;
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment
```

I've read many other SO questions regarding the NoClassDefFoundError, but I can't seem to resolve this issue. These are the things I've done:

- Cleaned the project
- Added **YouTubeAdnroidPlayerApi.jar**  to my libs folder
- Under "Order and Export" in the Java Build Path, I made sure YouTubePlayerApi.jar was checked.
- The YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar is listed under my libraries in my Java Build Path
- Ensured that I have a version of the YouTube app on the device that is compatible with the YouTube API (the phone has YouTube Version 5.3.24)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe fragments are supported pre-honeycomb (without appropriate compatibility libraries that is).

Try using `com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` instead.

See here for more information:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Comment: do you know of any examples of how to use this?  I'm new to android and haven't used fragments before.

Comment: This may help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302110/struggling-with-youtube-player-support-fragment/20363160#20363160

Answer (score 0):

```
please use the older API 1.0 I also have the same issue with 1.2.
```