# Infinite Loading youtube Api using youtubeSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, android-youtube-api

I'm using youtube support fragment in order to load a video for some reason it just loads without end.
its sepetated to two classes one is a fragment insede a tabbed activity and the other is the video fragment (couldnt use the fragment item directlly from the layout it casued null exeptions and led to [Struggling with Youtube Player Support Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302110/struggling-with-youtube-player-support-fragment))

im using the video code and not the url as supposed to, the permissions are ok and internet is working

is there a reason the video just keeps loading forever and wont start playing?

```
public class FragmentYouTubePlayer extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment 
implements  YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener 
{
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;   
    public static final String ARG_KEY_VIDEO_ID="ARG_KEY_VIDEO_ID";
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "a dev key in my code";
    private String _videoId;
    private YouTubePlayer _player;



    public static FragmentYouTubePlayer newInstance(String videoId) {

        FragmentYouTubePlayer playerYouTubeFrag = new FragmentYouTubePlayer();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ARG_KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);

        playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        return playerYouTubeFrag;
    }

    /**
     * enable the initialize of video
     */
    public void initVideo()
    {
         initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) 
    {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            _player=player;
            player.cueVideo(_videoId);
            player.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
        }
    }


    public YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return this;
    }

     @Override
     public void onDestroyView() {
         if(_player!=null) {

             _player.release();
         }
         super.onDestroyView();
     }
}
```

this fragment is called from this one:

```
public class FragmentVideo extends  Fragment 
{
    public static final String ARG_KEY_VIDEO_ID="ARG_KEY_VIDEO_ID";
    private FragmentYouTubePlayer _youTubePlayerFragment;
    private String _videoId;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.l_f_video,container,false);
        initData(view);
        initView(view);
        return view;
    }


    private void initData(View view) {
        _videoId=((MYActivity)getActivity()).get_video();
        _youTubePlayerFragment = FragmentYouTubePlayer.newInstance(_videoId);
    }

    private void initView(View view) {
        //swap framelayout with youtube fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
        replace(R.id.l_f_st_videoFragment, _youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        _youTubePlayerFragment.initVideo();
    }


}
```